# Create Enumeration of objects

Tags: java, enumeration, legacy

I need to create a `java.util.Enumeration` of Fruit objects so that I can pass it to this method during my test. It's a legacy code and I cannot change method signature.

```
public void get(Enumeration<Fruit> fruits){}
```

My fruit class:

```
public class Fruit{
    String name;
    //getters and setters   
}
```

How can I create an Enumeration of Fruit objects?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can use the [`Collections.enumeration(Collection<T>)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#enumeration-java.util.Collection-) method to convert a collection, such as a `List<Fruit>`, to `Enumeration<Fruit>`:

```
List<Fruit> fruits = new ArrayList<>();
fruits.add(new Fruit());
Enumeration<Fruit> fruitEnumeration = Collections.enumeration(fruits);
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Collections.enumeration()` to convert from a `Collection<T>` (which includes `List<T>`) to an `Enumeration<T>`. An example (blatantly stolen from [here](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/collections_enumeration.htm)):

```
package com.tutorialspoint;

import java.util.*;

public class CollectionsDemo {
   public static void main(String args[]) {
       // create an ArrayList
       List arrayList = new ArrayList();

       // populate the list
       arrayList.add("A");
       arrayList.add("B");
       arrayList.add("C");  

       // create an Enumeration
       Enumeration e = Collections.enumeration(arrayList);

       System.out.println("Printing the enumeration:");

       while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
            System.out.println("Value is: " + e.nextElement());
       }
   }    
}
```